# count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable|array in php 8

Tags: php, mysql

```
public function query($sql, $params = []){
    $this->_error = false;
    if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if (count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }
        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            $this->_lastInsetID = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }
```

code working in php 7.2 but not 7.4 & php 8

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable|array, string given in

when use **is_countable**
another error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/8.0.2
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.0.2
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
PHP version: 8.0.2
Version information: 5.0.4

```
public function query($sql, $params = []){
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query=$this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $x=1;
            if (count($params)){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
        

            if($this->_query->execute()){
                $this->_result=$this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                $this->_lastInsetID=$this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
            }else {
                $this->_error=true;
            }
        }
    return $this;
    }


public function insert($table, $fields = []){
    $fieldString='';
    $valueString ='';
    $values =[];

    foreach($fields as $field => $value){
        $fieldString .='`' . $field . '`,';
        $valueString .= '?,';
        $values[] = $value;
    }
    $fieldString = rtrim($fieldString, ',');
    $valueString = rtrim($valueString, ',');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$fieldString}) VALUES ({$valueString})";
    dnd($sql);

    if(!$this->query($sql, $value)->error()){
        return true;
        
    }
    return false;
}
```

Value where i pass

```
public function registerAction(){       
    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $fields = [
        'fname' => 'Name',
        'lname' => 'name',
        'email' => 'email@mail.com'
    ];
    $accountQ = $db->insert('account', $fields);

    
}
```

Comment: I doubt your code was working in PHP 7.2. you were just getting a warning instead of an error. The message is clear enough. What help do you need from us?

Comment: You need to check the places where you call this method, not the method itself. Somewhere you pass a string instead of an array.

Comment: Side note: you don't need `if (count($params))` before the `foreach`. If `foreach` receives an empty array, it simply won't run (it won't produce any notices/warnings). Of course, removing that condition won't solve your current problem (you would only replace it with an "Invalid argument supplied for foreach"), I'm just saying that in general you don't need it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoTUSL2m9uY&list=PLFPkAJFH7I0keB1qpWk5qVVUYdNLTEUs3&index=22&t=193s

Comment: $fields=[
   'fname' => 'fname',
   'lname' => 'lname',
   'email' => 'email@gmail.com'
  ];

Comment: hi @TangentiallyPerpendicular updated questions please check

Answer (score 0):

PHP has been doing this since version 7.2 - parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable interface. You pass a string to this method and hence the problem. The `is_countable` function saves the situation, but you have some error in your sql query. You may be using a keyword without enclosing it between `